# Display a message before exiting the iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, terminate

Is there any method that I could display a message before sending the app to the background by  pressing the home button?

And the app should be stays in the foreground until the user responds to the message being displayed.

Comment: It would help if you'd explain why you want to do this. We may be able to suggest better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: 1. Please don't, it's *annoying.* 2. But still **don't believe those who say "it's impossible"** - everything is possible, at most on jailbroken devices only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

though you cant stop ur app from going to background, I have a thought...

you can schedule a `UILocalNotificaiton` in `applicationWillEnterBackground` and trigger it immediately. Your app will surely move to background but this way you can display ur message  there and if user interacts with your message with "Action" button rather than "Cancel", your application will return back in active state.

just sharing my thought.. might be of ur help as I don't exactly know what's ur purpose behind such implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. Once the home button is pressed you lose control of the app and there isn't really anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this.

As you will press home button, then you will loose control of your app. 
And also apple will not allowed to do changes with basic device features.

Comment: Exactly, Apple will not allow anything that tries to overpower the functionality of home button

Answer (score 2):

Answer for your question is : No Way!

There is no Apple-supported method to terminate your application programmatically with an Alert.

When an iPhone user presses the Home button, he will be well aware that he needs to quit ! So "a message" make no sense there!

Answer (score 0):

Try `applicationWillResignActive` in `ApplicationDelegate.m`, and use `performSelector:@selector(showAlert:) waitUntilDone:YES.`

I am not sure that will work, but you try with that.
And, you may also want to assign the alert's delegate for action on some button press.

Comment: Tried this. Although the method is being called, the app still goes to background.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by your own logic. Add `UIAlertView` in `applicationWillEnterBackground`, and in response of `UIAlertView` you can take action whether to go to background or stay in foreground.

Comment: There is no such `applicationWillEnterBackground` method, and even if you're referring to `applicationWillResignActive`, you don't have a choice whether your app is going to the background.  You *can* implement a hack (that Apple won't approve), as in SamFisher's answer.